# Error When deploying Salesforce lightning / Aura components with Eclipse

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to deploy a Salesforce lightning coponent thorugh Eclipse from one dev org to another but I am receiving below errors.
I am able to succesfully install the components  through an unmanaged package but would like to konw if it is possible to deploy lightning components through Eclipse
Please see attached images for the errors.
[INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnM1n.png)

[Eclipse unknown data type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHqzn.png)

Answer (score 0):

For deploying aura components follow the steps below:
1) Open Package.xml in Ecllipse
2) Add following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```

3) Refresh your project from server

[image]

Regards,
Ajay

Comment: I already have the aura components in eclipse but I get an error when I a tremor to deploy, please view http://i.stack.imgur.com/LnM1n.png for screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deploy the complete aura folder to sandbox, i think you need to create a new project with aura components and its dependencies and try to deploy to the sandox.